# PHP stdClass & objects foreach

Tags: php

So I have some code looking like this at the moment:

```
    $filter = new \stdClass();

    $queryObj = $this->getpost['filter'];

    $filters = new \stdClass();
    $filters->team = $queryObj['team'];
    $filters->skill = $queryObj['skill'];
    $filters->division = $queryObj['division'];

    $filter->filters = $filters;
    $users = $managerStatistics->getManagerDeliveryData($filter);
```

I fellt the need to do this because in the getManagerDeliveryData(§filter), there is a "foreach $filter->filters"..

Does anyone know how to do this in a better looking way? This looks messy to me but I'm not sure what to do here..

Comment: What exactly looks messy to you here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite the way you build the data into a more compact format, casting each array definition to an object as needed...

```
$filter = (object) [
        "filters" => (object) [ 'team' => $queryObj['team'], 
                'skill' => $queryObj['skill'], 
                'division' => $queryObj['division'] ]
];
```

Comment: This is what I'm talking about, wonder when these things will start coming naturally :(

Answer (score 0):

If you cast an associative array to an object, it becomes a `stdClass` object with matching properties. Here's a generic example:

```
$arr = ['one' => 'foo', 'two' => 'bar', 'three' => 'meh']; 
$obj = (object) $arr;   

var_dump($obj);
```

This would give you:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["one"] · string(3) "foo"
    ["two"] · string(3) "bar"
    ["three"] · string(3) "meh"
}
```

In your case, you could do the following, if you're hoping to not have to name your `$queryObj` keys/values one by one (which is necessary if e.g. the filter list isn't fixed, and therefore can't be hard-coded):

```
$filters = (object) $queryObj;
```

Obviously, *every* key/value pair in the source array then becomes a property/value pair in the object. If there are particular values you want to omit, either unset them or use `array_intersect_key()` etc. functions to only cast the desired keys. Suppose your `$queryObject` had a bunch of keys, but you only wanted the ones in your example, you could do this:

```
$keymap = ['team', 'skill', 'division'];
$filters = (object) array_intersect_key(array_flip($keymap), $queryObject);
```